# Problem with loops on Pandas DataFrame Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqWba.jpg)

I am facing problem in converting DataFrame A to DataFrame B. I have tried using the `.transpose()` method. However, it did not work. Please help if you can. I cannot share the code, as it is confidential.

Comment: Please don't post images - post text. See [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: @DebokySaha To add more color to the comment above, we can't help you if we don't know what you're starting with.  If you've written code somewhere like `df = pd.DataFrame([1,2...])` then we can see what you're doing with it and how to help you get what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved it. From the next time, I will be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Please check these functions:

1. [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)
2. [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)
3. [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

Also, converting your df (or parts of it) to dictionary may be useful: [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).